# Prove that if $f \in H(D(0,1))$ and $f\left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \in \mathbb{R}$ for $n=2,3\cdots$ , then $f = \overline{f}$ on $D(0,1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f \in H(D(0,1))$ and $$\begin{align*}
f\left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \in   \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}$$ for all $n=2,3,\cdots$ .

Then I want to show that $$\begin{align*}
f = \overline{f}
\end{align*}$$ That is, $f$ is real on the unit disk.

Since $f$ is holomorphic on $D(0,1)$ , I expand $f$ by Taylor series and plug in $\frac{1}{n}$ . Then I have  $$\begin{align*}
f\left( \frac{1}{n} \right) = f(0) + f'(0) \frac{1}{n} + \frac{f''(0)}{2n ^{2}} + \frac{f^{(3)}(0)}{3! n^{3}} + \cdots 
\end{align*}$$ Since $f\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)$ are real for all $n=2,3\cdots$ and $f$ is continuous at $0$ , by taking the limit, I think $f(0) \in \mathbb{R}$ too.

Then I get stuck on showing $f$ is real on $D(0,1)$. Indeed, if $f$ is holomorphic, it should satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equation. Thus if $f$ is real on $D(0,1)$, it must have zero as its imaginary part, so we can know $f$ is a real constant on $D(0,1)$. Hence, I tried to show that $f$ is a real constant.

I tried to use the mean value property $$\begin{align*}
f(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(re^{i\theta}) \ d\theta
\end{align*}$$ Since $0<r<R$ is arbitrary, if I can show $f(re^{i\theta})$ is real, then I'm done. But I failed here, or maybe I'm not using a suitable method here. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: does there exist such a non constant function ?

Comment: if $f$ and $\overline{f}$ both are analytic then function must be constant .

Comment: Do you mean $f(z) = \overline{f(\overline z)}$? Otherwise it's false as stated (consider $f(z) = z$)

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the set $S = \{ z \in D(0, 1): f(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}\}.$ Note that by hypothesis, $\{0, \frac{1}{n}: n \geq 2\} \subseteq S$ ($0 \in S$ follows from the continuity of $f$). Now $\overline{f(\overline{z})} =: g(z)$ is also holomorphic, so by the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) it follows that $f = g$ on $D(0, 1).$ However, note that this is all you can say about your function, as for example $z \mapsto e^z$ clearly satisfies your hypothesis, yet it is obviously not real. I hope this helps. :)